# How to kill process on port on Windows when the port cannot be opened?

Tags: windows, cmd, localhost, port, pid

I'm on a Windows machine. Typically, when I need to kill a process on a port I do the following:

`netstat -ano | findstr : <PORT>`

After that command, the Process Identifier (PID) should appear and using that PID, I would do:

`taskkill /PID <PID> /F`

Then there's a response that the process has been terminated.

My issue now is that I'd like to kill the process on port 27017. So that I can use that port for a connection to Mongo. When I run: `taskkill /PID 27017 /F` I get the response `FINDSTR: Cannot open 27017`. Is there a way around this so that I can kill the task on that port. I've tried to restart as well, but that's not really doing me any good.

Any help would be appreciate and thanks in advance!

Comment: I was able to find the PID with `netsata -a -n -o`. It was PID 5888. But when I ran `taskkill /PID 5888  /F` I got the message: `The process with PID 5888 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied. ` any ideas how to overcome this access. The port used to be accessible...

Comment: The process that opened the port can be a system service and you can have not enough rights to kill it. It's also a bad idea to kill unknown processes. In case of a service you can run a `sc stop` command for this  service.